# c++ unsigned char array allocation - segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, memset, unsigned-char

I can't figure out what seems to be the problem that I get a segmentation fault from this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>

void alloc(unsigned char *data) {
    data = (unsigned char *) malloc(20);
    memset(data, 0, 20);
}

void main() {
    unsigned char *data = NULL;
    int i;
    alloc(data);
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        data[i] = i;
        printf("%d ", *(data + i));
    }
    free(data);
}
```

Unsigned char is 1 byte so the loop through 20 should be correct

Comment: You need to pass unsigned char** data to the alloc function and then use *data = (unsigned char *) malloc(20); or like Baum mit Augen said use a reference to the pointer.

Comment: If you try to learn C++ like this, you need to throw your current book / tutorial away and get a [better one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Well, looking at it again it's C++ since he's using `<cstring>`... Otherwise it looks completely like C

Comment: If you used a debugger (or even print statements), you should have seen that `data` was not changed after the call to `alloc`, and that it is still `NULL`.  That should have given a clue as to what is happening wrt passing-by-value and temporaries.   This is why debugging your code is important -- so that you 1) don't waste time asking on SO because you would have known the reason for the issue and/or 2) You would be able to ask a more focused question such as "why hasn't my pointer changed?"

Comment: Rolled back the changes bc OP specifically asked about C++ both in title and in tags, and this is not C because `<cstring>`. This edit conflicted with the author's intend.

Comment: ^^ what @PaulMcKenzie says.  Questions that indicate that no debugging was done should be closed as ... something.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a trivial debugging effort would have revealed the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your program is written in C instead of C++. In C++ you should use operator new [] instead of malloc.

The problem with the function is that function parameters are its local variables. So the function parameter `char *data` is a **copy** of its argument declared in main like

```
unsigned char *data = NULL;
```

So any changes of the parameter in function `alloc` do not influence on the original argument. After exiting the function the parameter (local variable) will be destroyed and the original variable in main will not be changed.

You have two approaches. Either you declare the function the following way

```
void alloc(unsigned char **data) {
    *data = (unsigned char *) malloc( 20 );
    if ( *data ) memset( *data, 0, 20 );
}
```

and call it like

```
alloc( &data );
```

Or you declare the function the following way

```
unsigned char * alloc() {
    unsigned char *data = (unsigned char *) malloc( 20 );

    if ( data ) memset( data, 0, 20 );

    return data;
}
```

and call it in main like

```
data = alloc();
```

Take into account that function main shall be decalred in C like

```
int main( void )
^^^
```

and in C++ like

```
int main()
^^^
```

Answer (score 7):

```
void alloc(unsigned char *data) {
    data = (unsigned char *) malloc(20);
    memset(data, 0, 20);
}
```

modifies a local *copy* of your pointer. You could pass it by reference to make your example work:

```
void alloc(unsigned char *&data) {
    data = (unsigned char *) malloc(20);
    memset(data, 0, 20);
}
```

Comment: if the alloc() function argument is a pointer, shouldn't it be passed by reference by default?

Comment: @IoanFulgeanu everything in C++ (except for plain C arrays that decay into pointers) is pass by value by default, even pointers.

Comment: @IoanFulgeanu No, the pointer itself still gets passed by value. You seem to be confused because you can use the copy of the pointer to access whatever it points to, which then is the same object the pointer you gave to the function points to.

Answer (score 0):

You could also return the pointer, rather than passing it to the function.

```
unsigned char *alloc() {
    unsigned char *data = (unsigned char *) malloc(20);
    memset(data, 0, 20);
    return data;
}
```

And then,

```
...
unsigned char *data = alloc();
int i;
...
```

You tagged C++, but your code looks like C. If you really are trying to write C++ you shouldn't be using malloc. Either use new[] or the appropriate smart pointers.

EDIT: You're using void main(). Don't do that.
[What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)